# Can't get previous element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, traversal

I need to get the previous element of an element found by using "contains" - prev and prevAll('span') aren't working. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("label:contains('Group')").prev().addClass("spMargin"); 
    });
</script>

<span class="radio"></span>
<label>Travel</label>

<span class="radio">(need to add class to this element!)</span>
<label>Group</label>
```

Comment: Are you looking at the source in your browser's inspector, or the "View Source" menu option?

Comment: What version of jquery are you using and in what browser? I created a jsfiddle to test this and it seems to work fine. example http://jsfiddle.net/k5mBM/

Answer (score 3):

Using `.prev()` works for me.  See http://jsfiddle.net/tT9Qu/